# Select certain values in an object for my box-plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am using the data frame pumpkin_data to try and plot a box plot for the weights of pumpkins in the United States and United Kingdom only. I have managed to get the box-plot to display all data in the object country, but I do not know how to isolate the two variables I want without displaying any other countries.

The code I used can be displayed below:

```
ggplot(pumpkin_data,aes(weight_lbs,country)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image: My box-plot using all of country]

I tried setting these as variables and applying it to the boxplot.

```
UK_var <- pumpkin_data$country =="United Kingdom"
US_var <- pumpkin_data$country =="United States"
```

```
ggplot(pumpkin_data,aes(weight_lbs,(UK_var, US_var))) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: If you just want to how the UK and the US then subset your data , i.e. try `ggplot(subset(pumpkin_data, country %in% c("United Kingdom", "United States")), ,aes(weight_lbs,country)) + geom_boxplot()`.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a couple of different ways:

### Filter inside ggplot call

```
ggplot(pumpkin_data %>% filter(country %in% c("United States", "United Kingdom")),aes(weight_lbs,country)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

### Filter before ggplot call

```
pumpkin_data_subset <- pumpkin_data %>% filter(country %in% c("United States", "United Kingdom"))

ggplot(pumpkin_data_subset,aes(weight_lbs,country)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```